# Quickly and efficiently calculating an eigenvector for known eigenvalue

Tags: python, matlab, linear-algebra, numeric, eigenvector

**Short version of my question**:

What would be the optimal way of calculating an eigenvector for a matrix `A`, if we already know the eigenvalue belonging to the eigenvector?

**Longer explanation**:

I have a large stochastic matrix `A` which, because it is stochastic, has a non-negative left eigenvector `x` (such that `A^Tx=x`).

I'm looking for quick and efficient methods of numerically calculating this vector. (Preferrably in MATLAB or numpy/scipy - since both of these wrap around ARPACK/LAPACK, any one would be fine).

I know that `1` is the largest eigenvalue of `A`, so I know that calling something like this Python code:

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs
vals, vecs = eigs(A, k=1)
```

will result in `vals = 1` and `vecs` equalling the vector I need.

However, the thing that bothers me here is that calculating eigenvalues is, in general, a more difficult operation than solving a linear system, and, in general, if a matrix `M` has eigenvalue `l`, then finding the appropriate eigenvector is a matter of solving the equation `(M - 1 * I) * x = 0`, which is, in theory at least, an operation that is simpler than calculating an eigenvalue, since we are only solving a linear system, more specifically, finding the nullspace of a matrix.

However, I find that all methods of nullspace calculation in `MATLAB` rely on `svd` calculation, a process I cannot afford to perform on a matrix of my size. I also cannot call solvers on the linear equation, because they all only find one solution, and that solution is `0` (which, yes, is a solution, but not the one I need).

Is there any way to avoid calls to `eigs`-like function to solve my problem more quickly than by calculating the largest eigenvalue and accompanying eigenvector?

Comment: Are you concerned with **only** finding the largest eigenvector or eigenvalue?  If that's the case, consider using the Power Method.  It is an iterative algorithm that simultaneously determines the most prominent eigenvector and eigenvalue: http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~ewoolgar/labs/linalg/Lab15.pdf.  It certainly is much more efficient than doing a full out SVD.

Comment: @rayryeng Actually, MATLAB uses ARPACK to find the largest eigenpair even more quickly than a regular Power Method. But the main focus of my question is this: Since I already *know* what the largest eigenvalue is, does there exist a method to find the corresponding eigenvector that is *better* than methods that simply find the largest eigenpair?

Comment: That unfortunately I don't have the answer to.  I'm also curious to know what the answer is!  Hope someone is able to answer your question (Amro, chappjc, horchler).

Comment: I've pinged Amro and chappjc to bring attention to your post.  Hope they'll be able to solve your problem!

Comment: To dig a little deeper: What is your matrix size? Does it have any special structure? (sparse, triangle, symmetric, positive definite,...) Do you want a single eigenvector corresponding to your eigenvalue or all of them (in case there are others)? Do you need to compute these for many matrices?

Comment: @knedlsepp The matrix is, well, let's just say large. Anything from several 10k to one million rows (and columns, since it is square). It is a sparse stochastic matrix, not symmetric. I know the eigenspace for eigenvalue `1` has dimension 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one approach using Matlab:

1. Let **x** denote the (row) left<sup>†</sup> eigenvector associated to eigenvalue 1. It satisfies the system of linear equations (or matrix equation) **xA** = **x**, or **x**(**A**−**I**)=**0**.
2. To avoid the all-zeros solution to that system of equations, remove the first equation and arbitrarily set the first entry of **x** to 1 in the remaining equations.
3. Solve those remaining equations (with **x**<sub>1</sub> = 1) to obtain the other entries of **x**.

Example using Matlab:

```matlab
>> A = [.6 .1 .3
        .2 .7 .1
        .5 .1 .4]; %// example stochastic matrix
>> x = [1, -A(1, 2:end)/(A(2:end, 2:end)-eye(size(A,1)-1))]
x =
   1.000000000000000   0.529411764705882   0.588235294117647
>> x*A %// check
ans =
   1.000000000000000   0.529411764705882   0.588235294117647
```

Note that the code `-A(1, 2:end)/(A(2:end, 2:end)-eye(size(A,1)-1))` is step 3.

In your formulation you define **x** to be a (*column*) right eigenvector of **A**<sup>T</sup> (such that **A**<sup>T</sup>**x** = **x**). This is just `x.'` from the above code:

```matlab
>> x = x.'
x =
   1.000000000000000
   0.529411764705882
   0.588235294117647
>> A.'*x %// check
ans =
   1.000000000000000
   0.529411764705882
   0.588235294117647
```

You can of course *normalize* the eigenvector to sum 1:

```matlab
>> x = x/sum(x)
x =
   0.472222222222222
   0.250000000000000
   0.277777777777778
>> A.'*x %'// check
ans =
   0.472222222222222
   0.250000000000000
   0.277777777777778
```

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> Following the [usual convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix). Equivalently, this corresponds to a *right* eigenvector of the *transposed* matrix.</sup>

Comment: Nice approach.  I also thought about setting a random vector `b`, then solving the equation `(A-I)(y) = (A-I)b`and then setting `x=y-b`, since `(A-I)b = (A-I)(x+b) = (A-I)x + (A-I)b` implies that `(A-I)(x)=0`. Your case is an example of this for a specific `b`.